# Programando no Ubuntu, IDE com problema

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Boa tarde, estou migrando para o ubuntu e procurando uma IDE boa com visual clean, eis que encontro o "Builder" e ao tentar utilizar o programa dois erros são exibidos mas felizmente um já solucionado. O erro que persiste é o seguinte:

autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: running: autopoint --force
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force 
configure.ac:102: error: m4_defn: undefined macro: LT_PACKAGE_VERSION
m4/libtool.m4:40: LT_PREREQ is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1

Já instalei o autopoint mas até o momento nada.

Comment: Uma pergunta, você vai desenvolver em que ? Tem uma lista interessante aqui:
https://www.linuxdescomplicado.com.br/2014/01/as-10-melhores-ides-de-programcao-para.html Eu uso muito o SublimeText3 com plugins

Answer (score 1):

Tente realizar o seguinte procedimento.

Adicione este dois repositórios:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Agora atualize.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

E tente instalar novamente..